# Different plasticity mechanisms in different species

Tags: neuroscience, animal-cognition, plasticity

Are the neural plasticity mechanisms behind learning essentially the same across different species? For instance, is STDP assumed to be a standard mechanism in almost anything with a brain, or is it only found in mammalian brains? Cephalopods seem like they have vastly different neural architectures at a macro-level - but are things pretty much the same at the synaptic/neural level?